# Android: MediaPlayer.seekTo inaccureate on streaming video (m3u8)

Tags: android, video, streaming, m3u8

I'm writing a video player using the `VideoView` class. I have a "forward" button and I want the player to seek a 10 seconds further, when a user presses it:

```
if (mVideoView.canSeekForward()) {
    int position = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() + SEEK_TIME;
    mVideoView.seekTo(position);
}
```

But almost always the position after seeking differs much from the desired: for example if `position` was **33458** in the code above, in my `OnSeekCompleteListener.onSeekComplete` I would get something like **29742** after calling `mVideoView.getCurrentPosition()`

This happens with [this video](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8) and any other **m3u8** videos I tried (on Nexus 7, API 19 and Xperia Z, API 17). But with some other streaming videos I don't encounter this bug.

Are there any workarounds? When I tried to play this video in MX Player, it had no problems with seeking, but probably it doesn't use the standard components